# How can I fill down a selection from dynamic starting point?

Tags: vba, selection, autofill

I have the following code to select data in column A to E as the starting point will be dynamic.

```
ActiveSheet.Columns("A:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
```

How can I then fill down this data to the length of column F?

Example Spreadsheet.
[image]

The starting point of the selection will not always be from row 2.

For example the data could look like this.
[image: Example Spreadsheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename "Sheet1" to the sheet name that your data is in

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRowA = ws.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'Finds last used row of column A
LastRowF = ws.Range("F" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'Finds last used row of column F

'Fills down column by column
ws.Range("A" & LastRowA).AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("A" & LastRowA & ":A" & LastRowF), Type:=xlFillValues
ws.Range("B" & LastRowA).AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("B" & LastRowA & ":B" & LastRowF), Type:=xlFillValues
ws.Range("C" & LastRowA).AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("C" & LastRowA & ":C" & LastRowF), Type:=xlFillValues
ws.Range("D" & LastRowA).AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("D" & LastRowA & ":D" & LastRowF), Type:=xlFillValues
ws.Range("E" & LastRowA).AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("E" & LastRowA & ":E" & LastRowF), Type:=xlFillValues
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting a autofill method range class failed error message when running this. I've tried declaring LastRowA and LastRowF but no luck `Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRowA As Long
Dim LastRowF As Long`

Comment: @noobatexcel Did you rename the sheet in `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")`? Because it works exactly as intended for the example spreadsheet you've shown

Comment: Thanks, I got that to work however it is just filling down from the last line. I need it to fill the highlighted rows in the example spreadsheet above. For example Row 3 should contain A's, Row 4 should contain B's etc instead of it just filling B's from the last row.

Comment: @noobatexcel Go to the first row of your data and add this formula in Cell A1: `=CHAR(64+ROW(A1))` and then drag that formula across to Cell E1. Then run the code again